# Do "beta" apps installed on iPod expire when their provisioning certificate does?

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing, ipod-touch

I have installed an app on
my iPod touch. Will this app expire when the provisioning certificate does?

EDIT:

I am the developer in this case. I installed it using XCode.   I used a development provisioning profile not a distribution one.  Does this change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install it? I assume it was sent to you by the developer along with the distribution certificate and you installed it via iTunes?

If so, then yes you will need to reinstall with an updated provisioning profile after your current one expires.

Comment: Yes, I just had this happen with some of my beta testers who had not switched over to the full version.  Ad hoc provisioning profiles eventually expire, and you need to keep updating the profile and the application to keep it valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about adhoc distribution, yes : you won't be able to launch "adhoc distributed applications" anymore once the adhoc provisioning profile installed on the iphone has expired. You will need to request a new "fresh" generated adhoc version.